# Finding the inverse of elementary matrices.

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

For each of these, I am supposed to examine what was done to I and do the opposite to get the inverse, right? so for $E_1$ it would be the same but with a $-1/2$, and $E_2$, it would be the same but with a $+2$ instead of $-2$, $E_3$ would be a $3$ instead of $1/3$ and $E_4$... would be... no solution? What would $E_4$ be?

Comment: $E_4$ is not invertible.

Comment: thanks. i take it i'm right about the first 3 also.

Comment: You can check yourself. Multiply a matrix by the matrix you suspect is its inverse, in either order. If the result is  the identity matrix, you got it right; if not the identity, you got it wrong.